# pylance client could not create connection to serve in vscode

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, server, ipynb

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2PX2.png)
specific physical server is connected in vscode and frequent disconnect in my machine only the same server is working fine in another machine.

specific physical server is connected in vscode . Three people are using that server but specifically i am getting problem in my machine/computer that pyclient server is not supported so again and again I need t uninstall and install the python in my server . sometimes it woe=rks and sometimes it takes more time and sometimes not works . How to resolve those issues.
when I try to run ipynb extension script it just keeps loading for simple import os itself and cell is not executing

Answer (score 0):

**Problem solution:**
Click on the extension on the left, find the Python Extension Pack, which is used to parse python code, uninstall it directly, and then reinstall it. After reinstalling, restart vscode and no more errors.

**Problem analysis:**
The compiler reports an error, and the Python code cannot be parsed. It can be inferred that there is an expansion error. The first reaction at this time is to uninstall and reinstall. In fact, Pylance is used to complete code, pop up prompts, etc. It needs to connect to a code parsing server, which is the server mentioned in the error report. This failed to connect, causing it to crash, and then blocking other subsequent expansions, eventually causing the entire python expansion to fail. Pylance is among a bunch of extensions included in the Python Extension Pack. You can also solve Pylance alone. The faster way is to reinstall the entire extension directly, and Pylance will naturally be repaired.